# RDD of gziped files to "uncompressed" Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bunch of compressed text files each line of which containing a JSON object. Simplified my workflow looks like this:

```
string_json = sc.textFile('/folder/with/gzip/textfiles/')
json_objects = string_json.map(make_a_json)
DataRDD = json_objects.map(extract_data_from_json)
DataDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(DataRDD,schema).collect()
'''followed by some transformations to the dataframe'''
```

Now, the code works fine. The problem arises as soon as the number files can not be evenly divided between executors.

That is as far as I understand it, because spark is not extracting the files and then distributing the rows to the executors, but rather each executioner gets one file to work with.

e.g If i have 5 files and 4 executors, the first 4 files are processed in parallel and then the 5th file.

Because the 5th is not being processed in parallel with the other 4 and cannot be divided between the 4 executors, it takes the same amount of time as the first 4 together.

This happens at every stages of the program.

Is there a way to transform this kind compartmentalized RDD either into a RDD or Dataframe that is not ?

Comment: I got an answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547646/rdd-of-gziped-files-to-uncompressed-dataframe/40547977#40547977

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was crossposted and answered already